# Navicat, Object DB and Postgres

Tags: database-connection, postgresql-9.2, intersystems-cache, data-import, navicat

I'm importing tables by Navicat Import Wizard (via ODBC connection) in Postgres. I have a problem when import from Caché Intersystem DB a table which allow object list-object. 
Example table Test

```
Id (int),
Name (varchar(10)),
Preferences (List <Objects>)
```

How could i manage Preferences column without change my schema? There are some features in Navicat Wizard Import?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find a solution right now. I have import my data as string pipe separated and i have managed collection data list using custom objects by Hibernate.